# Copy files from master branch from Gitlab to my server

Tags: php, python, continuous-integration, gitlab

I apologise I don't really know how to ask that question. I work on a project which is hosted on `gitlab.com` and I want to write a script that run on my server to get all files from my project's master branch and copy it to a specific folder to not have to do it manually.

My question is: how can I get this files using gitlab's API with language like `php` or `python` without setting up a git project on my server?

I look the documentation and make all the stuff to get an ssh key but I can't find how to simply get files from the master branch.

I don't need a full code but just the method to do it right

I hope my question is not too vague. I thank you in advance

Comment: @MilanG I specified that I didn't want to initiate a git project on my server so I will not be able to use git commands

Answer (score 0):

you can use ftp git https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp

its very good solution to push on gitlab and server at same time.

or you can use gitlab pipeline , create .gitlab-ci.yml file on your server with gitlab credentials  to connect your server to gitlab project 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/README.html

Comment: thank you for your answer but that doesn't answer at all the question that specifies not to use git

Comment: two ways donot need to install git on server @johannchopin

Comment: Heu ok and how ? `to push on gitlab and server at same time` need an `push` action from `git`

Comment: you push from your local to server , you need git on local only , "at same time" by adding hook in pre-push for your git config

Answer (score 0):

**The above problem can be solved by using python:**

you can do it by cloning all the repositories to a specific location in your server:

**Step 1)** Get the list of all the Repos in the gitlab which you want to clone,on this we will run the loop

getting all the repos:

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(git_url, private_token=your private token)
all_projects = gl.projects.list(all=True)
length=len(all_projects)
i=0
while i < length:
    project = gl.projects.get(all_projects[i].id)
    print(project.name)
    i=i+1
```

**Step 2)** Clone each Repo one by one to the location:

```
import pygit2

callbacks = 
pygit2.RemoteCallbacks(pygit2.UserPass("your_private_token", 'x-oauth-basic'))
    repoClone = pygit2.clone_repository("https://gitlab.com/test/testing.git", location_to_clone,checkout_branch=master,callbacks=callbacks)
```

**Full code:**

```
import pygit2
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(git_url, private_token=your private token)
all_projects = gl.projects.list(all=True)
length=len(all_projects)
i=0
callbacks = 
pygit2.RemoteCallbacks(pygit2.UserPass("your_private_token", 'x-oauth-basic'))
while i < length:
    project = gl.projects.get(all_projects[i].id)
    print(project.name)
    repoClone = pygit2.clone_repository("https://gitlab.com/test/"+project.name+".git", location_to_clone,checkout_branch=master,callbacks=callbacks)
    i=i+1
```